# i cant add data from sql to list of string

Tags: c#, sql, string

In this program I try to get data from SQL into a list of strings and show them in a `messageBox`. The program should start searching when I type one character in `textBox` and use this in the query as below:

```
string sql = " SELECT * FROM general WHERE element='" + textBox1.Text + "'  OR element='" + textBox2.Text + "' OR element='" + textBox3.Text + "' OR element='" + textBox4.Text + "'";


        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=localhost;user=mate;password=1234;database=element_database");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();


        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string rd;
        rd = reader.ToString();

        int i=0;
        List<string>  item = new List<string>();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            item.Add(rd["element"].ToString());//i got error in this line


        }

        for (i = 0; i < item.Count;i++ )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item[i]);

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a language tag!

Comment: whats the error u r getting for above code?

Comment: Use parameters instead + textbox.text +!  Probably you Element is null and can't be converted toString. Check the data on the table.

Comment: [check this][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370927/how-do-i-loop-through-rows-with-a-data-reader-in-c

I am also learning C# and it helps me understand the looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing wrong? a bunch of things:

In your question you write you gen an error but don't tell us what it is.
Exceptions has messages for a reason: so that you will be able to know what went wrong.

As to your code:

- You are concatenating values into your select statement instead of using [parameterized queries.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) This creates an opening for [sql injection attacks.](https://xkcd.com/327/)
- You are using an `SqlConnection` outside of a `using` statement.
  You should always use the `using` statement when dealing with `IDisposable` objects.
- You assume that `rd["element"]` always have a value.
  If it returns as `null` from the database, you will get a null reference exception when using .ToString() on it. The proper way is to put it's value into a local variable and check if this variable is not null before using the `.ToString()` method.
- You are using `rd` instead of `reader` in your code. the `rd` variable is meaningless, as it only contain the string representation of `MySqlDataReader` object.

Comment: Consider my answer as constructive criticism. Every programmer was a newbie once :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `rd` as string. You probably meant to use the reader object in this loop instead:

```
while (reader.Read())
    {
        item.Add(reader["element"].ToString());// change "rd" to "reader"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of modifing the SQL to use an IN instead of multiple or statements as well as including the use of parameter into the query and not a string based approach. This should solve your problems.

```
    string elem1 = "@elem1";
    string elem2 = "@elem2";
    string elem3 = "@elem3";
    string elem4 = "@elem4";
    List<string> parameters = new List<string>{ elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4 };

    string sql = string.Format(" SELECT * FROM general WHERE element IN ({0})", string.Join(',', parameters.ToArray()));

    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=localhost;user=mate;password=1234;database=element_database"))
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(elem1, textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(elem2, textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(elem3, textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(elem4, textBox4.Text);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string message = reader["element"] as string;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: invalid expression term string at List<> and invalid expression term 'params'

Comment: You are perfectly right, can't name a list to params. My apologize. The post has now been corrected.

Comment: that got some Error here 'string.Join(string, params string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Oops, my bad. Forgot that string.Join don't take a list as an argument. it needs to be an array.