# How to loop through a database table and create a button for column

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssms

I am trying to loop through a DB and create a button for each row based on my query. I should be getting 3 buttons in return however only one is being created.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 con.Open();
 string TeamID = (string)Session["TeamID"];
 SqlDataReader myReader = null;
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Players1 WHERE 
 TeamID = " + teamID, con);
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamID", TeamID);
 myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
 while (myReader.Read())
 {
   foreach (Object ob in myReader)
 {
  Button1.Text = "" + (myReader["Name"].ToString());
  }
 }
```

I should be getting 3 buttons based on the data in my DB

Answer (score 3):

You need to create or instantiate the `Button` object itself, and then assign value to it.

about getting data from your `myReader` object see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370927/how-do-i-loop-through-rows-with-a-data-reader-in-c)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
string TeamID = (string)Session["TeamID"];
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Players1 WHERE 
TeamID = " + teamID, con);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamID", TeamID);
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    foreach (Object ob in myReader)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "Btn_" + ob["Id"]; //I assume the table has an Id
        btn.Text = ob["Name"]; //I also assume the table has a Name column
        //for click events
        //btn.Click = btn_Click_Event; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I dunno exactly where you should be getting three buttons.
From what it looks like, you're just changing the text of Button1, which is a single button. 
You're changing the text of Button1 three times.
You want Button2 and Button3 to change as well, I guess.

Comment: Yes, but how do I dynamically create a button for each row in the DB

Comment: You really should either try to answer the question, or just not post an answer at all.